# Calling a delegate method inside a Block. Delegate changes

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have this code:

```
__block id <BitlyConnectionDelegate> blockDelegate = [self delegate];
__block BitlyConnection *blockSelf = self;

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

//do some stuff

[blockDelegate someMethod:blockSelf withParameters:parameters]; //calling a delegate method

}];
```

So I NSLoged the class of the delegate and before the block, the delegate class is correct, but it changes, sometimes the block delegate is __NSArrayI or __NSMutableRLEArray
And this causes the error:

> [__NSArrayI someMethod:withParameters] unrecognised selector sent to instance

The blockDelegate variable is changing but I do not know how it is changing and why.
Any tips / suggestions would be awesome. Explanations why it changes are much appreciated.

NOTE: I own both classes and wrote them myself.

Jack

Comment: Doesn't make a lot of sense, however not all delegate methods are required to exist, so the use of `respondsToSelector` should be used.  Also why are those variables using the `__block` qualifier (I'm sure you mean `__weak for second)`?

Comment: __block is used to access those variables inside a block.

Comment: No it's not, it's used to declare that you will be *writing* to those variables, which you aren't doing.  Remove the `__block` declarations and re-test.

Comment: wow nice, this did the trick :O thanks much! but it is required to make this variable as it crashed when I used self and self.delegate

Comment: No, that's something else.  Post another question and include the stack trace.